# How do I properly deal with Message Boundary Issue in Python TCP Socket Client/Server?

Tags: python, sockets, server, tcp, client-server

*Backstory: what I have done*

`{Codes at the bottom}` I've already coded the multithreaded client and server programs using python socket, with the help of the following sites:

> [I. Echo Client and Server](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/#echo-client-and-server)
>
> [II. Socket Server with Multiple Clients | Multithreading | Python](https://codezup.com/socket-server-with-multiple-clients-model-multithreading-python/)
>
> [III. Python Socket Receive Large Amount of Data](http://%20https://newbedev.com/python-socket-receive-large-amount-of-data)

### **Regarding Message Boundary**

I thought I successfully coped with the problem but then I was told that if my client sends a message with a size way too big, the network will break the message into different chunks, and then my current server won't be able to get the right message.

So I experimented and tried sending a super long message like "a..b..c..d.." (.. *indicates loads of the previous letter have been ommitted for convenience*) through the client and then it turns out the network breaks the message into something like "a..b..", "b..b", "b..c..", "c..c", "c..d..", "d..d" [Pattern: long, short, long, short, ...].

Oops! It was supposed to be one message! SO it seems that prefixing the message with its length isn't enough.

**What should I do to my code to fix this message boundary issue?**
(It'd be nice to see code solutions with explanation, many thanks)
**And  what other occasions did I not take into considerations and thus need fixing as well?**

[function: send_msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoDx8.png)

[function: recv_msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liNUG.png)

### **My Codes Currently**

*_server.py*

```
    import socket
    import os
    from _thread import *
    import struct # Here to convert Python data types into byte streams (in string) and back
    
    # ---- To Avoid Message Boundary Problem on top of TCP protocol ----
    def send_msg(sock: socket, msg):  # ---- Use this to send
        # Prefix each message with a 4-byte length (network byte order)
        msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
        sock.sendall(msg)
    
    def recv_msg(sock: socket):       # ---- Use this to receive
        # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
        raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
        if not raw_msglen:
            return None
        msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
        # Read the message data
        return recvall(sock, msglen)
    
    def recvall(sock: socket, n: int):
        # Helper function to receive n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
        data = bytearray()
        while len(data) < n:
            packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
            if not packet:
                return None
            data.extend(packet)
        return data
    
    # ---- Server Communication Setup
    
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
    PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
    ThreadCount = 0
    
    try: # create socket
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print ("Socket successfully created")
    except socket.error as err:
        print ("socket creation failed with error %s" %(err))
    
    try: # bind socket to an address
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(str(e))
    
    print('Waitiing for a Connection..')
    s.listen(3)
    
    def threaded_client(conn: socket):
        conn.send(str.encode('Welcome to the Server'))
        while True:
            # data = conn.recv(2048) # receive message from client
            data = recv_msg(conn)
            reply = 'Server Says: ' + data.decode('utf-8')
            if not data:
                break
            # conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
            send_msg(conn, str.encode(reply))
        conn.close()
    
    while True:
        Client, addr = s.accept()
        print('Connected to: ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
        start_new_thread(threaded_client, (Client, )) # Calling threaded_client() on a new thread
        ThreadCount += 1
        print('Thread Number: ' + str(ThreadCount))
    s.close()
```

*_client.py*

```
import socket
import struct # Here to convert Python data types into byte streams (in string) and back 

# ---- To Avoid Message Boundary Problem on top of TCP protocol ----
def send_msg(sock: socket, msg):  # ---- Use this to send
    # Prefix each message with a 4-byte length (network byte order)
    msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
    sock.sendall(msg)

def recv_msg(sock: socket):       # ---- Use this to receive
    # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
    raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
    # Read the message data
    return recvall(sock, msglen)

def recvall(sock: socket, n: int):
    # Helper function to receive n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
    data = bytearray()
    while len(data) < n:
        packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data.extend(packet)
    return data

# ---- Client Communication Setup ----

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 65432        # The port used by the server

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print ("Socket successfully created")
except socket.error as err:
    print ("socket creation failed with error %s" %(err))

print('Waiting for connection')
try:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

Response = s.recv(1024)
while True:
    Input = input('Say Something: ')
    # s.send(str.encode(Input))
    send_msg(s, str.encode(Input))
    # Response = s.recv(1024)
    Response = recv_msg(s)
    print(Response.decode('utf-8'))

s.close()
```

Comment: Please keep your question minimal. If the other parts are not needed to understand your question don't link to these. If it breaks with a specific message make the message part of the program so that everything can be reproduced by others. The code looks mostly fine to me except that you assume that the message length will always fit into 4 bytes (might be in your case), that you assume that a single recv will always give you the complete message length (no guarantee for this) and that you assume that the CPU architecture is the same in client and server (might be in your case).

Comment: TCP provides you with a "stream" abstraction. You put the stream of bytes it, and you get the same stream of bytes out. It does not provide any guarantees on timing though.  Whatever network does with the stream is TCP problem, not yours. Yes, long message will be broken down, and you might receive it in chunks, but eventually you will always receive the stream. You just need to prepare that receive will not receive all bytes at once and you may need to call it several times before you receive the N bytes you are expecting (and of course there is no time limit on when this happen).

Comment: If you have some kind of "messages", your problem is to have a stream of bytes and split it into messages. It would be alsmost the same as if you were reading it from a file, or from any other place where you can get a stream of bytes from.

Comment: That being said, i do not see a problem with having a length. If you need something more complicated than just having a length you can always consider [google protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers). But for the simple case, length should do it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you for pointing out the 3 new problems that I did not realize at all. 
[1. Message length byte size, 
 2. Yeah I realized when receiving, it actually receives multiple times separately, I guess I need a buffer to collect them? If so how exactly should I do it? 
 3. I had no idea CPU architecture would be a such a factor... Were you referring to the endian issue?]
And I'd like to address them all. So what exactly can I do to make my codes more compatitable and flexible? Gratitude.

Comment: @CodeofSpades: for size - either limit the size of the message or use more bytes to represent it or use some chunking (like having multiple blocks prefixed with size, then a final block with size=0). For CPU architecture - I just saw that you already enforce a specific endianess, so this should be fine. As for the rest - please provide a way to simply reproduce the problems you have.

Comment: @Effie Thank you! On "You just need to prepare that receive will not receive all bytes at once and you may need to call it several times before you receive the N bytes you are expecting (and of course there is no time limit on when this happen)", how do I prepare for it? For a long message, it usually seems to automatically receive for multiple times until all is through though(in my case).

Comment: idk, it seems to me that your rcvall function is doing exactly that. it calls recv from socket untill it has received all bytes.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich If I use the chunking method you mention, could you be so nice as to elaborate how I can do it? Wouldn't the network itself further chunk the chunks?  (I don't want to limit the sizes of their messages)

Comment: @Effie  yup right. Thanks anyways

Comment: From the application TCP is just a byte stream, i.e. any chunking done at the network layer can be ignored. To chunk your own message simply prefix each chunk with its size and then have a final chunk of size 0 to signal the end of message. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding for a similar concept in HTTP.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I just read the wiki document and understood the concept and appreciate the use of size 0 chunk as an end signal. But I don't know where to begin with to use this in my code. In this case, how would I know how many bytes I would need to read to inspect the length? And for the sender, by what rules should I chunk the data and into what sizes should I chunk my data?

Comment: @CodeofSpades: just use a fixed size length for the chunk as you use currently for the message. Only don't assume that a message is done after you've received the first chunk. Instead read until you got the last (zero-size) chunk. It does not really matter how you chunk the data at the sender side, provided the chunk size is less than the max chunk length possible.

Comment: And how do I take the user input and chunk it?

Comment: I see. Thanks so much!! @SteffenUllrich